# OpenID with Drupal 6/7

Tags: drupal, openid

In Drupal 6 (or even the upcoming 7) is it possible to use OpenID much like stackoverflow does?

For example:

1. Click 'login' and be sent to a login page where you can choose to login with any OpenID account (i.e. google, yahoo, facebook, wordpress...)
2. example - if you choose yahoo as the OpenID account, you are directed to yahoo, login there and then are redirected back
3. run the captcha check and agree to the terms and conditions
   get a username automatically assigned to you (i.e. User001234)
4. And that's all - registration done
5. Then be able to change your screenname and gravatar, and any other profile info

I think that steps 1-3 are possible, but can that be it for the registration process? I've read in several places that this is not possible with Drupal but the threads are either outdated or unclear as to what is being discussed - so I am unsure if they are correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I understand that this functionality may not be 'out of the box'. But by 'possible', I mean can it be done without consuming a year of my like developing a module for drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 1 & 2 are covered by [the Open Login module](http://drupal.org/project/openlogin). 3 is covered by [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom). 4, I think, can be accomplished by simply changing core Drupal settings to not require email verification. 5 can be accomplished by [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) for redirecting the user profile page on registration and [Gravatar](http://drupal.org/project/gravatar) for, well, gravatar.

Comment: Any idea if there is something like "the open login module" for drupal 7?